# Reactjs Get item Matches by ID

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I would like to edit an item but I receive a TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined.

I did not understand how matches url

in my component tableItem i have

```
<a className="no-decoration" href={`/updateMenu/${row?.id}`}>
    <EditIcon className="icon-action-table-grey" />
    </a>
```

and in updateMenu component  i want to matches id
in my state i put `menuId:  this.props.match?.params.id`

but i receive an error TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined.

could someone help me figure out what the problem is?

`console.log(this.props)` i get [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHsqZ.png)

Comment: it's saying this.props.match is undefined. then you're trying to get a value from undefined. What i suggest you to do first is console your this.props. It seems you haven't used the route HOC. what are you using how are you using the router in that component? provide more details if you need more help.

Comment: @ReyYoung if i console log this.props i haven't a match and i use `react-router-dom` in my app.js  ` <Route path="/updateMenu/:id">
            {token === null ? <Redirect to={`/login/?next=${'/updateMenu/:id'}`} /> : <UpdateMenu />}
          </Route>`

Comment: oh since you're using class components wrap your component by`WithRouter` hoc. Import it from react-router-dom. And use it as export default withRouter(App). then, you will have access to match. Also see this example here. 
https://reactrouter.com/web/api/withRouter